Dynamically setting column names in a view
I have a table called tblMain with the columns col_a, col_b, col_c



col_a
col_b
col_c




Mr A
01/01/1950
12345


Mr B
02/02/1950
99999


Mrs C
03/03//1950
111111



I then have a view where I set the names to be more meaningful:
select
    col_a AS [Customer Name]
    , col_b AS [Customer dob]
    , col_c AS [Customer Order ID]
from tblMain




Customer Name
Customer dob
Customer Order




Mr A
01/01/1950
12345


Mr B
02/02/1950
99999


Mrs C
03/03//1950
111111



However, I'd like to hold a mapping table where I can control the name of the outputted columns in the view dynamically.
So a new table called tblMapping with 3 columns table_name, table_field, view_name



table_name
table_field
view_name




tblMain
col_a
Customer Name


tblMain
col_b
Customer dob


tblMain
col_c
Order ID



As such, the view would 'look up' the table name / column in the mapping for each column in the view and name it as the view name. I know how to do it in python and it's relatively straight forward, but I'm not as proficient with SQL.
So something like (which I know is not right btw)
select
    col_a AS (select view_name from tblMapping where table_name = tbl1 and field_name = table_field)
    , col_b AS etc
    , col_c AS etc
from tblMain as tbl1

Could anyone point me in the right direction please?
Thanks

You're not meant to be able to do this because SQL is not designed to support it (SQL is not Python, they're completely incomparable). The fundamental problem here is that you shouldn't have this variant tblMain (let alone Hungarian Notation...): you need to fully normalize your data into separate tables with well-defined static invariants concerning column names and types first.

If you really had to do this, you would need to use dynamic sql

While this is a bad idea as Dai explained in a previous comment, and you can't directly run dynamic SQL in a view, this can still be done in a convoluted way by implementing a dynamic create or alter view in triggers on the mappings table - but I wouldn't recommend it in any way, this can only be a nice way to learn some tricks in TSQL, but in no way to be used in any production environment.

You aren't supposed to re-implement the database inside the database. And if you can't figure out this simple issue, i'm very sceptic you'll be able to figure out on how to use this dynamic table stuff later either, so just start simple and then later you can implement this gee-wiz dynamic solution

It's possible to dynamically create and alter database view definition with a sample query like below, but I don't feel this is a very safe practice in a production environment. Changing database column name might have 2 consequence: (1) other application/process is still pointing to the old names, and (2) the lost opportunity to enforce data integrity on content with a specific column name.
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @column1 NVARCHAR(100) = 'NewColumnName1';
DECLARE @column2 NVARCHAR(100) = 'NewColumnName2';

SET @sql = N'
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW MyView AS
SELECT 
    Column1 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@column1) + ',
    Column2 AS ' + QUOTENAME(@column2) + '
FROM MyTable;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

If column name needs to change often, and data integrity is not a primary concern, maybe use the data type, JSON, to store everything as a document. I think SQL Server started to support the data type, JSON, since SQL 2016.
You can created calculated columns, index, view ... etc., based on the JSON column. For example, vCustomerName below is a calculated column based on the JSON column, Info.
ALTER TABLE Sales.SalesOrderHeader ADD vCustomerName AS JSON_VALUE(Info,'$.Customer.Name')

Check out the Microsoft reference: Index JSON data. It has lots of examples.
